# Datepicker que no muestre la opción de selección de la hora

Tags: datepicker

Tengo un datepicker. Me deja seleccionar la hora, y no quiero que se muestre el botón que selecciona la hora; he logrado mediante formato que escoja solamente la fecha, pero quisiera que el botón de seleccionar la hora no aparezca.

```
<script src="{{ asset('assets/js/plugin/material-datetime-picker.js')}}"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
   
   const picker3 = new MaterialDatetimePicker()
        .on('submit', function (d) {
            $('#order-date').val(d.format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
            
        });
    const el3 = document.querySelector('#order-date');
    el3.addEventListener('click', function () {
        picker3.open();
    }, false);
</script>
```

Comment: proba si tenes disponible  un datepicker ( todo lo mismo pero sin "time" ), sino por lo general es un option onda `{ time:false }`

Comment: tienes razon @al

Answer (score 0):

tienes razon @alo Malbarez tan sencillo como incluir este codigo

```
.c-datepicker--show-time {
    display:none
}
```

Comment: je, iba mas por el lado de probar un `new MaterialDatePicker()` ( aunque habría q ver si está definido en el js de assets ) o como option en el constructor `new MaterialDatetimePicker({ time:false })`